# Longest processing time rule on unrelated machines

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I am trying to solve the job secheduling problem using the Longest processing time rule, that is: We seek to minimize the makespan by first sorting the jobs in decreasing order of processing time, then the algorithm makes one pass through the jobs in any order; when it comes to job $j$, it assigns $j$ to the machine whose load is smallest so far.

When the machines are idential, this is a $\frac{3}{2}$-approximation algorithm. But how about when the machines have different speeds? Let's say for example that we have 2 machines, one machine has speed 1 and the other one has seep 2. How would we calculate the lower bounds for this algorithm?

What I tried:

- If we have less or equal jobs than machines, then $OPT \geq \frac{1}{2}max_j p_j$ (where $p_j$ is the processing times of a job).
- If we have more jobs than machines, then $OPT \geq p_j$

But this yields a 3-approximation algorithm if we sum the inequalities. Is this correct?